# Swift and Parse.com : relational query

Tags: swift, parse-platform, relational

On parse.com, I have a table named "ExerciseInstance" with a "pointer" to the "_User" table (with the user's objectId).

In my Swift code, I want to get all the rows from ExerciseInstance with UserAccount<_User>  = "MZmMHtobwQ"

This does not work:

```
predicate = NSPredicate(format:"userAccount == %@", "MZmMHtobwQ")
var query = PFQuery(className:"ExerciseInstance", predicate:predicate)
```

Same problem with:

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"ExerciseInstance")
query.whereKey("userAccount", equalTo: "MZmMHtobwQ")
```

Any idea - what am I missing?
Best,
Tom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot check to see if it is Equal to the objectId of the user, you must create the object first:

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"ExerciseInstance")
query.whereKey("userAccount", equalTo: PFObject(withoutDataWithClassName:"_User", objectId:"MZmMHtobwQ"))
```

Comment: Great answer! You should check out our new opening here at Parse's Platform Services Engineering team :) https://parse.com/jobs

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var teamQuery = PFQuery(className:"Team")
teamQuery.whereKey("winPct", greaterThan:0.5)
var userQuery = PFUser.query()
userQuery!.whereKey("hometown", matchesKey:"city", inQuery:teamQuery)
userQuery!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
(results: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
     if error == nil {
     // results will contain users with a hometown team with a winning record
   }
}
```